# Why we define the completeness of a space by the converge of a Cauchy sequence rather than a normal sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The intuition of the completeness to me is that the limit of any sequence converges to the point inside the set itself.
But why we define a set to be complete as any Cauchy sequence converge into the set itself? It seems a more complex definition than a simple convergent sequence. Why we use Cauchy sequence rather than a simple sequence?

For the simple sequence, can we use $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_n=x$?

Comment: What do you mean by normal sequence or simple sequence?

Comment: Because, Cauchy sequences always converge; in the case the space is not complete, they just converge to something that is outside of the space.

Comment: @Aweygan, can we define it as the edited question? Or do you mean that convergent is defined by Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Your intuition is off.  In any metric space with more than one point, there are always sequences that **don't** converge.  In particular, a sequence that is not a Cauchy sequence can't converge.  For example, a sequence that alternates between two different points.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can I just require that the sequence is convergent?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to say: Lets define complete to be a space in which for every convergent sequence its limit(s) belong to the space. Observe that such a definition would make every space complete, because by definition the limit points of convergent sequences are points of the space. In metric spaces, convergent sequences are Cauchy. But the converse is not true in general. The notion of completeness is intended to be spaces (metric or at least [[[Cauchy spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_space)]]) in which the converse holds.

Comment: For example, choose $\Bbb Q$ for the space (with usual distance). This is a metric space. Now, each member of the sequence $(1+\tfrac 1 n)^n$ is rational (i.e., belongs to the space). But it does not converge in $\Bbb Q$. It is not a convergent sequence. But it is a Cauchy sequence. Therefore, $\Bbb Q$ is not complete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're doing is positing an existing "ambient complete space" $Y$ within which the space $X$ you care about lives. That is, you want to say

> $(*)\quad$ $X$ is complete if every $\color{red}{\mbox{convergent}}$ sequence of elements of $X$  converges to an element of $X$

However, this has a serious problem: what does the red "convergent" mean? If we take that to mean convergent *in the sense of $X$*, then every space is complete in this sense.

To make $(*)$ work as a notion of completeness, we need to have an ambient space $Y$ which we're using as our guide to what sequences "really converge." In many cases it's clear what $Y$ should be - e.g. (with the usual metric) for $X=\mathbb{Q}$ we clearly want $Y=\mathbb{R}$ - but in general this starts us down a dangerous road: for a really weird metric space $X$, how would you go about finding the right $Y$?

---

Instead, we want to define completeness in a "self-contained" way: the statement "$X$ is complete" should only make reference to $X$ itself, not any presupposed ambient space. This is where Cauchy sequences come in: to tell if a sequence of elements of $X$ is Cauchy, we don't need any ambient space to live in - Cauchyness is determined fully within $X$. Intuitively, a sequence is Cauchy if it "ought to" converge, and that's where we get the *right* definition of completeness from:

> $(**)\quad$ $X$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges in $X$.

Incidentally, with this definition in hand we can appropriately make $(*)$ a *theorem*, as follows:

- First, we show that every metric space $X$ has a [**completion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion) $\hat{X}$. *Roughly speaking, points in $\hat{X}$ are "named" by Cauchy sequences from $X$, and for each point $x$ in $X$ the constant sequence $(x,x,x,x,...)$ "names" $x$ in $\hat{X}$ so that we can think of $X$ as literally being a subset of $\hat{X}$. The details are more complicated - for one thing, multiple Cauchy sequences might name the same point! - but this is the basic idea.*
- This is the ambient space we wanted in $(*)$! We can now prove that $X$ is complete iff every sequence of elements of $X$ which is convergent in the sense of $\hat{X}$, converges to something in $X$ *(in the sense of either $X$ or $\hat{X}$; they'll agree on this)*.

---

**Remark**: This is an example of a more general phenomenon: that in mathematics, we frequently want to consider objects "on their own" as opposed to embedded in some larger "background object." This often makes things harder to visualize, but the payoff is huge. For one thing, it broadens the range of objects we can talk about (e.g. in this case, $(**)$ lets us talk about the (in)completeness of metric spaces without any obvious "background"). For another, it can free us from ultimately misleading intuitions. A good example of this is the idea of *intrinsic dimension*: if we insist on thinking of surfaces as embedded in an ambient space it's natural to say that the hollow sphere is three-dimensional while the Klein bottle is four-dimensional, but the right way to think about things turns out to be that they're *each* two-dimensional.

Comment: Very nicely explained!

Comment: Oh wow! They enabled scrolling for equations. The web designers of this website are going for a clunky look.

Comment: @fatherBrown Did that improve the formatting?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, but the complain wasn't about your choices. The web designers are the ones that should have not made those scroll bars appear where are not needed, specially the vertical one.